# rendered tag in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tabpanel, conditional-rendering

I have an application that uses JSF implementation 2.1.29 Sun JSF RI integrated with Spring 3.1.0 and Richfaces 4.3.7 with the following code:

```
<h:form>
<a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{searchBean.activeTab}">
    .....
</a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>

<h:form>
<a4j:outputPanel id="searchPanel">
    <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{searchBean.activeTab2}">

                <div class="formline">
                    <div class="formLabelGrueso">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['search.height']}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formTextCorto oblig">
                        <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.form.height}" required="true" label="#{msgs['search.height']}" maxlength="6">
                            <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="50.00" maximum="300.00" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formLabelGrueso">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['searchBean.weight]}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formTextCorto">
                        <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.form.weight}" label="#{msgs['searchBean.weight]}" maxlength="6">
                            <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1.00" maximum="199.00" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </div>
                </div>      
        <a4j:commandButton action="#{searchBean.advancedSearch}" execute="@this" id="buttonDefault"
            render="searchPanel" value="#{msgs['user.button.search']}"></a4j:commandButton> 
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</<a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

The ManagedBean is managed by spring framework with the following code:

```
@Component
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
public class SearchBean{
    private boolean activeTab;

    private boolean activeTab2;

    ....
}
```

when I do submit, running on the server #{searchBean.activeTab} and #{searchBean.activeTab2} methods. Why both methods are executed when really only makes a ajax call that renders the "searchPanel" panel?. Should not run only #{searchBean.activeTab2} method ?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but by default `<a4j:outputPanel>` will rerender with each AJAX request, even if you don't put its id into @render; to disable that add `ajaxRendered="false"`.

Comment: The problem is not <a4j:outputPanel> tag, if change <a4j:outputPanel> by <h:panelGrid> both methods is still running when the ajax call is made.